# Laravel Server keep starting and closing

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel. After installing the composer this problem occurs. I change the port number to 1000 but nothing changed. So don't know what to do.

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDev>php artisan view: clear //view clear                                                                       Compiled views cleared!
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\WebDev>php artisan serve                                                                           
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8000
[Mon Oct 12 22:21:43 2020] PHP 7.4.10 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
[Mon Oct 12 22:22:05 2020] 127.0.0.1:50516 Accepted
[Mon Oct 12 22:22:05 2020] 127.0.0.1:50517 Accepted
[Mon Oct 12 22:22:05 2020] 127.0.0.1:50516 Closing
[Mon Oct 12 22:22:05 2020] 127.0.0.1:50517 [200]: GET /favicon.ico
[Mon Oct 12 22:22:05 2020] 127.0.0.1:50517 Closing
```

Comment: to change port do this `php artisan serve --port=1000`

Comment: Cna you try `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/`

Answer (score 0):

laravel custom port serve,
for example, you want on the `localhost:1000`

```
php artisan serve --host=localhost --port=1000
```

sometimes you got an error, already port uses, for that you should kill process

you can kill `php artisan` of  process

```
kilall php
```

that command make kill all PHP process
also, you have other preference
find a process which uses the port, and kill it
for find process for which one port uses

```
sudo fuser -v -n tcp 8000
```

you can kill process as such

```
kill -9 <process-id>
```

and again call command `php artisan serve --port=1000`
shortly

```
php artisan serve --host=localhost --port=1000
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I think it's related to the port 8000. Maybe it's already in use or something like this because when I changed the port to 9000 (ie: `php artisan server --port=9000`) it solved the issue and works just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Disable smadav auto block, you can find it on the smadav icon, bottom right conner of your screen

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).